# Hidden POST request to PHP

Tags: php, post

I know I can use POST to hide the parameters in the url, but the data can still be seen in the network tab when I inspect element. Is there a way to completely hide what data is sent?
So no one can intercept the data.

Comment: No, You can't do that in HTTP, But in HTTPS you can try.

Comment: HTTPS should do the trick.

Comment: use session or encrypt one side and decrypt another side before get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use encryption. This involves enabling SSL over the HTTP connection. You will need to configure your server for this if it's not configured for it already.

Using HTTPS (SSL over HTTP, also known as Secure HTTP) allows your data to be sent and received over a secure connection.

If you're using the Developer Tools of WebKit (Google Chrome, etc.) then you'll always be able to see the data because you're the one making the request. It doesn't hide the data from you.

Answer (score 4):

let's use HTTPS protocol, attacker can capture data but they cannot read them.